# How to prevent particular hyphenations of a word *without* specifying allowed hyphenations

Tags: hyphenation

The `\hyphenation` command can be used to list the allowed hyphenated forms of words. For example, `\hyphenation{incor-rect-ly}` means that these hyphenations of the word *incorrectly* are allowed.

Is there a complimentary command that allows one to list the **disallowed** hyphenations of a word? I do not want to list all of the allowed versions. For example, I want to say `\nohyphenation{in-correctly}` **without** specifying the allowed versions. I'm lazy/efficient and don't want to think too hard about many-syllable words.

Comment: Only the setting for the last word in `\hyphenation{incorrectly incor-rectly incorrect-ly}` will be taken into account (but only if you set hyphenmins to a smaller value). Use `\hyphenation{incor-rect-ly} ` to describe all the allowed hyphenations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from your answer it seems you don’t really understand what `\hyphenation` does.

The purpose of `\hyphenation{some-word-with-hyphens}` is not just to allow TeX to hyphenate the word at the places where the hyphens are: it’s also to forbid it everywhere else.  For example, say you want to add a breakpoint to the word “advised” by allowing a break before “ed” at the end (the correct hyphenation is “ad-vised” in any style of English typography).  The only way you can do that is by saying `\hyphenation{ad-vis-ed}`; if you say `\hyphenation{advis-ed}` you will have forbidden the hyphenation “ad-” which is ...  ill-advised.

To address your issue, we would need to introduce *two* complementary commands, which we could call `\allowhyphenation` and `\forbidhyphenation`, for example.  I can’t see an easy way to do so with the current implementation of TeX’s hyphenation algorithm; it seems that you would have to add patterns tailored to the word so that it would either allow or forbid a specific breakpoint, which is rather awkward.  Alternatively, you could write a function to scan the word for all its hyphenation breakpoints, add or remove some of them as mandated by the command that has just been issued, and feed it to `\hyphenation` again.  None of this is particularly straightforward.  You’re far better off using `\hyphenation` for what it’s be designed to do: to specify all the desired breakpoints in a word.  You may find that they're not that bad after all.  Obviously, there may be errors too; if you do find any please report it [here](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen).

Of course, if you’re using LuaTeX, all bets are off as you can replace the entire hyphenation algorithm by a new one implemented in Lua.